# changing an android service to execute at specific intervals

Tags: android, service

I'm using an android example of a service that gets current location, it works fine but I would like to know what changes I would have to make so it only checked for the current location at specific time intervals (e.g. every 2 minutes), instead of just doing it continuously.

```
public class YourService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager mLocationManager;

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // This won't be a bound service, so simply return null
    Log.v("WEAVER_", "Service_OnBind...");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // This will be called when your Service is created for the first time
    // Just do any operations you need in this method.
    Log.v("WEAVER_", "Service_OnCreate...");

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1,
            1, this);


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("WEAVER_","Service_OnDestroy");
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    mLocationManager = null;
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.v("WEAVER_","Service_Location Change");

    String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
            + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();








      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}



@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact intentions for this, but it might be worth for you to look into using an IntentService instead of a Service. The IntentService will run in a separate thread and not in the main thread and also you can start it, the intent service will do what you intend it to do, that is fetch the location, and then it finishes itelf.

Then for the duration time there are several ways of doing this but I would recommend you to have a look at:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

If you go for an IntentService you simply call (some context).startService when the AlarmManager triggers.
Alternative you could have the Service always active (If you return START_STICKY in onStartCommand) and do the alarm in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I was able to do to check the location at intervals. This uses the GoogleAPIClient, so you will need to add that to your project if you want this to work. This solution also needs you to use the LocationRequest and FusedLocationProviderApi.

Declare GoogleAPIClient like this:

```
public class YourService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private static GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private static FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private static LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000); // look at provider every 5 seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // or one second if its convenient
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        googleApiClient.connect();
        ... // other code here
    }
```

Then, add the locationRequest to fusedLocation like:

```
@Override // This is called when googleApiClient has connected
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    fusedLocation.requestLocationUpdates(<googleApiClient here>, locationRequest, this);
}
```

Hope this helps. If you want, I could also show you how to do something like this using timertask